# Get value from attribute and update dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have created a dynamic input. Every generated inputs row has two dropdown menus. The first input named "select_product[]", which gets items from the DB. I have created an attribute [data-wh] in the product name as the below line

```
echo"<option data-wh='$wh'  value ='$i->s_id'>".$i->s_name. "</option>";
```

data-wh printing the warehouses ID separated by comma example data-wh='1,2,6'

regarding the select_product[] I want another dropdown "warehouse[]" get changes the output if the warehouse id=data-wh.

after a very long search I found a below lines that might drive me to achieve it but no luck.

```
<script>
$("#product_name").on('change', function(slc) {
    var values = $(this).val().split(',') //split value which is selected
    $("#warehouse option").hide() //hide all options from slect box
    //loop through values
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var vals = values[i]
        $("#warehouse option[value=" + vals + "]").show()//show that option

    }
})</script>
```

Also, please check my all code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mohamed Syam">

    <title>New Invoice | <?php echo $userdata[0]['s_name'];?></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.min.js.download"></script>

    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/0a3b9034e109d88d72f83c9e6c9d13b7.js.download"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />


</head>

<body >

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <?php include_once('nav_v.php');?>

    <!-- Page Content -->

    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Invoice</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if($this->session->flashdata('done')): ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <strong>Success!</strong> <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('done'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php if($this->session->flashdata('error')): ?>
                <div class="alert alert-warning">
                    <strong>Warning!</strong> <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
            <!-- ... Your content goes here ... -->

            <?php $form=array('id'=>'myform');?>
            <?php echo form_open('Order/submit',$form);?>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Header</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" name="customer_name">
                            <option disabled selected> Vendor</option>
                            <?php foreach ($vendors as $v):
                                echo "<option  value ='$v->v_id'>" . $v->v_name . "</option>";
                            endforeach;
                            ?>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="invoice_number" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9./]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');"   placeholder="Invoice Number"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="date" data-provide="datepicker"  class="form-control" name="Invoice_date" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="text"   class="form-control" name="invoice_desc" placeholder="Description" />
                    </div>
                </div><!--customer panel-Body-->
                <div class="panel-heading">Invoice Details
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div id="education_fields">


                        <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" id="product_name" name="select_product[]">
                                    <option selected disabled>Select Item</option>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach($items as $i):

                                        $wh=trim($i->whs);
                                        $wh=preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', ',', $wh);
                                        echo"<option data-wh='$wh'  value ='$i->s_id'>".$i->s_name. "</option>";
                                    endforeach;
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
                            <div class="form-group">

                                <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" id="warehouse" name="warehouse[]">
                                    <?php if (count($uwh) > 1){echo "<option selected disabled>Select Warehouse</option>";}?>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach($uwh as $w):
                                        echo"<option  value ='$w->w_id'>".$w->w_name. "</option>";
                                    endforeach;
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control qty"  name="qty[]" value="" placeholder="Quantity">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control total"  name="total[]" value="" placeholder="Total" readonly >
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"  onclick="education_fields();"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer"><small>Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus gs"></span> to add another item field :)</small>, <small>Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus gs"></span> to remove the last item :)</small></div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Order Now </button>
            <?php echo form_close();?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
<!-- /#page-wrapper -->

<!-- /#wrapper -->




<script>

    var room = 0;
    function education_fields() {

        room++;
        var objTo = document.getElementById('education_fields');
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
        var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
        var medo='<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" name="select_product[]"><option disabled value="">Select Item</option><?php if(count($items) > 1){?> <option selected disabled>Select Item</option><?php } foreach($items as $i){ ?><option data-wh="<?php echo $i->s_name; ?>"  value =""><?php echo $i->s_name; ?></option> <?php }  ?></select></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" name="warehouse[]"><?php foreach($uwh as $w){?> <option  value ="<?php echo $w->w_id;?>"><?php echo $w->w_name;?> </option>;<?php } ?></select></div></div> <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="qty[]" value="" placeholder="Quantity"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"> <input type="text"  class="form-control total"  name="total[]" placeholder="Total" readonly /><div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_education_fields('+ room +');"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';

        divtest.innerHTML = medo;
        objTo.appendChild(divtest);
        $('select').selectpicker();
    }
    function remove_education_fields(rid) {
        $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
    }
</script>

<script>
    $("#product_name").on('change', function(slc) {
        var values = $(this).val().split(',') //split value which is selected
        $("#warehouse option").hide() //hide all options from slect box
        //loop through values
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            var vals = values[i]
            $("#warehouse option[value=" + vals + "]").show()//show that option

        }
    })

</script>



<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/startmin.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made changes to HTML and jQuery function lines.

**HTML** I created a new class for the Select [.Prod] element and made the jQuery execute while the Select element effects and changes.

```
                      <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <select class="selectpicker prod"  data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" name="select_product[]">
                                <option selected disabled>Select Item</option>
                                <?php
                                foreach($items as $i):

                                    $wh=trim($i->whs);
                                    $wh=preg_replace('/[ ,]+/', ',', $wh);
                                    echo"<option data-wh='$wh'  value ='$i->s_id'>".$i->s_name. "</option>";
                                endforeach;
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true"  name="warehouse[]">
                                <?php if (count($uwh) > 1){echo "<option selected disabled>Select Warehouse</option>";}?>
                                <?php
                                foreach($uwh as $w):
                                    echo"<option  value ='$w->w_id'>".$w->w_name. "</option>";
                                endforeach;
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**jQuery** I called to element data-wh into array. and for loop displays the other select element if the value included into the first Select element.

```
    <script>
//  $(".prod").on('change', function() {
        $(document).on('change', '.prod', function () {
        //var values = $(this).val().split(',') //split value which is selected
        var values = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-wh').split(',')
        $(this).parent().parent().next().find('option').hide()
        //loop through values
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            var vals = values[i]
            //$("#warehouse option[value=" + vals + "]").show()//show that option
            $(this).parent().parent().next().find('option[value="'+vals+'"]').show()
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')
        }
    }
    )

</script>
```